# multiple DS18B20 error: 'list index out of range'

Tags: ds18b20

I power a RPi 4B, and DS18B20 sensors. My aim is to  build an measurement system for our heating system. With 15-20 temperature senors.

- Useing 4,7 kOhm pullup Resistor to 3 V
- Powering star typology
- VCC 3 V
- useing python in two files: DS18B20classfile_sleep4.py and DS18B20multiple_time.py
- long sensor cable over 30 m included

But I started small, with one to four sensors. 1 sensor works Ok (no problems for 1 week run time). But, if I use more, I get after a several days following error.

'list index out of range'

I am wondering very much. Because, a few days it seems to be fine. And later there comes the error.

After reading the error. I can start compileing without any problem. Hence, It might be only a temporary problem?
What might be the reason?
you find my code below the text. I got it from AZ-delivery. Did just a few changes (timestamp and sleep.time)

Hopeing for your advices

greetings
Gari

DS18B20classfile_sleep4.py

```
import os
import glob
import time

class DS18B20:
    
    def __init__(self):
        os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
        os.system('modprobe w1-therm')
        base_dir = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/'
        device_folder = glob.glob(base_dir + '28*')
        self._count_devices = len(device_folder)
        self._devices = list()
        i = 0
        while i < self._count_devices:
            self._devices.append(device_folder[i] + '/w1_slave')
            i += 1
            
    def device_names(self):
        names = list()
        for i in range(self._count_devices):
            names.append(self._devices[i])
            temp = names[i][20:35]
            names[i] = temp
            
        return names
    
    def _read_temp(self, index):
        f = open(self._devices[index], 'r')
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        time.sleep(4)
        return lines
    
    def tempC(self, index = 0):
        lines = self._read_temp(index)
        retries = 5
        while (lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES') and (retries > 0):
          print('wait')
          time.sleep(4)
          lines = self._read_temp(index)
          retries -=1
          
        if retries == 0:
            return 998
        
        equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
        if equals_pos !=-1:
            temp = lines[1][equals_pos + 2:]
            return float(temp) / 1000
        else:
            return 999 # error
        
    def device_count(self):
        return self._count_devices
```

DS18B20multiple_time.py

```
import time
from DS18B20classfile_sleep4 import DS18B20

degree_sign = u'\xb0' # degree sign
devices = DS18B20()
count = devices.device_count()
names = devices.device_names()

print('[press ctrl+c to end the script]')
try: # Main program loop
    while True:
        i = 0
        print('\nReading temperature, number of sensors: {}'
              .format(count))
        while i < count:
            container = devices.tempC(i)
            print('{}.temp: {:.3f}{}C, {:.3f}{}F of the device {}'
                  .format(i+1, container, degree_sign, container * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0, degree_sign, names[i]), time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
            i = i + 1
            
        time.sleep(1)
        
    # Scavenging work after the end of the program
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Script end!')
```

Comment: [this](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/1/148.html) has lots and lots of information - at a guess, the Pi does not provide sufficient drive current for what you want to achieve